# If statement re-direct not working as expected

Tags: javascript, validation, if-statement

I'm trying to learn javascript through dummy scenarios, the below will not be used in a live context. All of the html pages are on my home server which is why i havent used http:// etc in the link.

I'm trying to have the below code take me to the "index" page if I type in the correct username and password and remain on the "home" page if I type it incorrectly but with an alert stating "Invalid Login". If I type in the correct username and password i'm redirected correctly *however* I'm also redirected to the index page if I enter in an incorrect username/password after the alert is correctly triggered.

How can I stop the index page loading for the wrong username/password? I'm sure its probably something simple i'm missing!

This is the html of the homepage

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">

<div id="loginbox">
<form id="login" action="home.html">
Username: <input type="text" name="user" id="user"><br>
Password: &nbsp;<input type="password" name="password" id="password"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="checkUserName()">
</form>

</div>
</div>
```

and this is the script

```
function checkUserName() {
var User = document.getElementById("user").value;
var Password = document.getElementById("password").value;

if (User === "user123" && Password === "password123") {
    window.location = "index.html";
}
else  {
    alert("Invalid Login");
}
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: You declared your button as a submit type. That's what causes that behaviour. Replace the input with a <button>

Comment: You've just submitted the form. `onclick="checkUserName(); return false"`. Or use a non-obtrusive technique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont want to submit the form in this case. You just need to invoke the js function on click of login. So use a normal button instead a submit.

```
<button onclick="checkUserName()">login</button>
```

When you use a submit button, the form will get submitted unless you are not preventing the default action by `e.preventDefault()` or by returning `false` from the js function being called

```js
function checkUserName() {
var User = document.getElementById("user").value;
var Password = document.getElementById("password").value;

if (User === "user123" && Password === "password123") {
    window.location = "index.html";
}
else  {
    alert("Invalid Login");
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">

<div id="loginbox">
<form id="login" action="home.html">
Username: <input type="text" name="user" id="user"><br>
Password: &nbsp;<input type="password" name="password" id="password"><br>
<button onclick="checkUserName()">login</button>
</form>

</div>
</div>
```